# What does the Klingon phrase in this ritual mean?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon-language

In the Next Generation episode *Reunion*, prior to a new chancellor of the Klingon Empire being chosen, a ritual is performed to confirm the previous chancellor is dead.

First the arbiter of succession says the phrase "Qab jiH nagil!" before stabbing the deceased chancellor with a device called a painstick, then the two (if not more) contenders do the same, one after the other.

Can anyone say what "Qab jiH nagil!" is supposed to mean?

Comment: You could google that phrase and find out it means "Face me if you dare!" in under 10 seconds...

Comment: @KeithMorrison- I tried that- only the first time I forgot the exclamation point and didn't get results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [original screenplay](https://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/181.txt);

> Both parties look expectantly at Picard. K'Ehleyr hands the painstik
> to Picard. He moves forward and stands before K'mpec's corpse.
>
> **PICARD:** ***Qab... jIH... nagil (Face me if you dare!)***
>
> He places the end of the painstik on K'mpec's chest and there is an
> ELECTRIC BUZZ as the stick discharges.